# Excluding records that are greater than yesterdays date

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a date field that is CYYMMDD in numeric format. I wanted to get rid of the century so I did the Formula Field:

If {field} <> 0 then {field}-1000000

This gives me a date in numeric format of YYMMDD example 150922

I now want to filter the field to only show me records from yesterday.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I don't think subtracting the century will help, you'll need to use the `DATEADD` function to subtract one day and then you can compare it to the value with the century.

Answer (score 0):

Create two formula.

1st to convert the number(YYMMDD) to date format.

2nd to find out yesterday date..

@NumberToDate

CDate(ToNumber(Mid(ToText({NumberDate}),1,2)),ToNumber(Mid(ToText({NumberDate}),3,2)),ToNumber(Mid(ToText({NumberDate}),5,2)))

@YesterdayDate

currentdate -1

then apply filter on date where @NumberToDate >= @YesterdayDate

Answer (score 0):

to avoid performance issues always try to convert date field to the data type your have in your database. So you will write this in your record selection formula

```
(yourdatefield) = tonumber((yourcentury)&totext(currentdate-1,'yyMMdd'))
```

that is going to convert yesterday date to YYMMDD format and add the century to it and then convert it to your database filed data type.

hope that helps!